# Open URL in new Safari tab with AppleScript

Tags: macos, safari, applescript

Is it possible to use AppleScript to open a link in a new tab in Safari?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This will work:

```
tell application "Safari"
    tell window 1
        set current tab to (make new tab with properties {URL:"http://www.stackoverflow.com"})
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Doesn't work in 5.1, [applescript - Script Safari 5.1 to open a tab - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941630/script-safari-5-1-to-open-a-tab)

Comment: @Lri: Doesn't work in 6.0 either; given the half-abandoned AppleScript support even in Apple's own applications, out-sourcing the task to a shell command using the `open` utility is the most robust approach:
`do shell script "open -a \"Safari\" \"" & "http://stackoverflow.com" & "\""`

Comment: This works fine in Safari 9.1.2.  Is it possible to always open a new window rather add the tab in the existing window?

Answer (score 29):

I think this also does what you asked for, but it is much shorter and is less browser-specific:

```
do shell script "open http://www.webpagehere.com"
```

This will open the specified URL in your default browser. And if you explicitly want to open it in Safari, use this:

```
do shell script "open -a Safari 'http://www.webpagehere.com'"
```

Answer (score 14):

This should usually create a new tab and focus it (or focus an existing tab if the URL is already open):

```
tell application "Safari"
    open location "http://stackoverflow.com"
    activate
end tell
```

It opens a new window if "Open pages in tabs instead of windows" is set to never though.

`tell application "System Events" to open location` doesn't work with some URLs that contain non-ASCII characters:

```
set u to "http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/漢字"
tell application "System Events" to open location u
--tell application "Safari" to open location u
--do shell script "open " & quoted form of u
```

This opens a new tab even when new pages are set to open in windows:

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    reopen
    tell (window 1 where (its document is not missing value))
        if name of its document is not "Untitled" then set current tab to (make new tab)
        set index to 1
    end tell
    set URL of document 1 to "http://stackoverflow.com"
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari"
    perform action "AXRaise" of window 1
end tell
```

`set index to 1` doesn't raise the window, but it makes the window appear as `window 1` to System Events, which can `AXRaise` it.

Comment: open location seems to open windows or tabs based on the "Open pages in tabs instead of windows" preference setting -- the make new tab version creates tabs even if Safari is otherwise configured to always open windows.

Comment: Perfect for my usage, since I don't want it to create a new tab if the previous one is still open. Thank you.

Comment: hi @Lri i need some help.. your code is working for me only for non-ascii, i tried for ascii... it opens in new tab, but i want it in same tab.. can you please help

Answer (score 6):

I've been using the following script to open hundreds of docs into tabs in a single window.

```
tell application "Safari"
    tell window 1
        make new tab with properties {URL:"http://foo.com/bar"}
        make new tab with properties {URL:"http://foo.com/baz"}
    end tell
end tell
```

But that no longer works in Safari 5.1 on Lion. It would open the new tab, but it wouldn't load the URL provided in the properties glob. I modified it to the following, which now works:

```
tell application "Safari"
    tell window 1
        set URL of (make new tab) to "http://foo.com/bar"
        set make new tab to "http://foo.com/baz"
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 3):

Code:

```
tell application "System Events"
tell application "Safari" to activate
tell process "Safari"
click menu item "New Tab" of menu "File" of menu bar 1
end tell
end tell

tell application "Safari"
set URL of document 1 to "http://www.stackoverflow.com/"
end tell
```

One problem is that this only works if the system's language is set to English.

Answer (score 3):

It's been a while since a new answer's been posted here. I think this is the optimal way to do this. It will open Safari if it's not open, create a new window if there are no windows open, and add the tab to the current (or newly created) window.

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    try
        tell window 1 to set current tab to make new tab with properties {URL:theURL}
    on error
        open location theURL
    end try
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment :-/ so I will answer to say that Tim's answer (above) works as of OS X 10.8.5. This one-line version of his script also works:

```
tell window 1 of application "Safari" to set current tab to (make new tab with properties {URL:"http://www.stackoverflow.com"})
```

Arrgh -- the one line is overflowing. Here it is without the code tags:

tell window 1 of application "Safari" to set current tab to (make new tab with properties {URL:"http://www.stackoverflow.com"})

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using automator to do this which was much easier and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following approach:

```
//make Safari window active and topmost
tell application "Safari" to activate
//start communication with Safari
tell application "Safari"
    tell window 1
        //create new tab and open specified URL
        tab with properties {URL:"https://url.com"})
        //make tab active
        set visible to true
    end tell
end tell
```

Also u can combine usage of Apple script within [FastScript](https://red-sweater.com/fastscripts/) (free for 10 shortcut)

To add your script - just save script in `/Library/Scripts`. After you will be able to set some shortcut for new script.

If you want to open new Window than new tab u can play within next:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
        click menu item "New window" of menu "File" of menu bar 1
    end tell
end tell
```

Note: you need to allow AppleScript to use specialCapabilities in security settings in this case.

Comment: Please add explanations to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not the shortest solution but also works, and not only in English ...

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    set frontmost of process "Safari" to true
    keystroke "t" using {command down}
end tell

set myURL to "anyurl.html"
delay 2
tell application "Safari" to set the URL of the front document to myURL
```

Comment: IMO this doesn't really introduce any new value.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me in Safari v.11

```
tell application "Safari"
    tell window 1
        make new tab with properties {URL:"https://twitter.com"}
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to open a new tab in the background with Safari.

```
tell application "Safari"

set the URL of (make new tab in window 1) to "your.url.net"

end tell
```

During the time I wrote this answer I made this

```
tell application "Safari"

try

    display dialog "Website URL" default answer "" buttons {"OK", "Annuler"} default button 1

    set theURL to text returned of result

    set netProto to "https://"

    if theURL contains netProto then

        set the URL of (make new tab in window 1) to theURL

    else

        set the URL of (make new tab in window 1) to netProto & theURL

    end if

end try

end tell
```

New version

```
tell application "Safari"

repeat

    try

        display dialog "Website URL" default answer "" buttons {"OK", "Annuler"} default button 1

        set theURL to text returned of result

        if theURL is "" then exit repeat

        set netProto to "https://"

        if theURL contains netProto then

            set the URL of (make new tab in window 1) to theURL

        else

            set the URL of (make new tab in window 1) to netProto & theURL

        end if

        display dialog "Do you want to open a new tab?" buttons {"Yes", "No"} default button "Yes"

        if button returned of result is "No" then exit repeat

    end try

end repeat

end tell
```

Any suggestions will be appreciate

Best regards