# Script Safari 5.1 to open a tab

Tags: safari, applescript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Open URL in new Safari tab with AppleScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892622/open-url-in-new-safari-tab-with-applescript)

How do I tell Safari to open a URL in a new tab of the current window?

This is a duplicate of [Open URL in new Safari tab with AppleScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892622/open-url-in-new-safari-tab-with-applescript), however its answer no longer works with the current version of Safari (5.1 on 10.6.8). The tab is created but empty:

```
tell front window of application "Safari"
make new tab with properties {URL:"http://www.stackoverflow.com"}
end tell
```

If you make a new "document" instead the URL is honored, but this opens a window.

For what it's worth, I reported this as a bug to Apple. But a workaround would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have the latest Safari here, but this might work

```
tell front window of application "Safari"
    set newTab to make new tab
    set the URL of newTab to "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
    set the current tab to newTab
end tell
```

Comment: It does. Why didn't I think of that?

Comment: @Tobias: Well, your original code should've worked, so why _would_ you think of this convoluted way? :)

Comment: That won't work if the `front window` isn't a browser window. (E.g. if Safari isn't open, has no windows or some other type of window is focused.)

Comment: @Lri: It won't, no, but that's trivial to check and handle using `number of windows` and adding a try…catch or checking the front window's properties

Comment: I posted another answer at [osx - Open URL in new Safari tab with AppleScript - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892622/open-url-in-new-safari-tab-with-applescript).