# Google Chrome doesn't open URL with AppleScript

Tags: macos, google-chrome, editor, applescript

What I have set up is a AppleScript that asks you what website you want to open with a couple options, to make this simple, I only list one option, Google. This is the current code:

```
if the_button = "Google" then
    site = "http://www.google.com"
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        launch
        tell window 1
            make new tab with properties {URL:site}
            repeat while loading of active tab
                delay 0.1
            end repeat
        end tell
        activate
    end tell
```

It opens a new tab in Google Chrome, but doesn't put anything in the URL bar or reload/load or anything. I've tried this: [Script Safari 5.1 to open a tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941630/script-safari-5-1-to-open-a-tab) But, nothing's working. I'm using Mac OS X Lion 10.7.4 and Google Chrome version 21.0.1180.79. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

It works for me, but not when Chrome doesn't have open windows or if all windows are minimized. You could add a `reopen` command to open a new default window or unminimize a window in those cases.

```
set site to "http://www.google.com"
tell application "Google Chrome"
    reopen
    activate
    tell window 1
        make new tab with properties {URL:site}
    end tell
end tell
```

Another option might be to use something like `do shell script "open " & quoted form of "http://google.com" & " -a Google\ Chrome"`. It's often closer to the default behavior of browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just do this?

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    set theSite to "http://www.google.com/"
    open location theSite
end tell
```

The “open location” command is part of Standard Additions and is available to all Mac apps. It’s the default way to open a website in any Mac app. You might notice that Safari’s AppleScript dictionary doesn’t even include a way to open a website — it simply uses the standard “open location” command which you can find in the Standard Additions dictionary.