# How to invoke browser from Mac OS X command line (for Behat BDD testing)?

Tags: macos, shell, behat

In Behat testing you have an context to "show last response" of a step in test scenario. This fires up a browser window with static html of last response. But running this on mac os returns an error:

`sh: x-www-browser: command not found`

Any idea how to setup this command to a specific browser (e.g. chrome)?

Answer (score 6):

So, in a terminal on my Mac, (OSX 10.5.8), I type:

```
 open -a Firefox
```

and Firefox opens up.

When I type:

```
open -a opera
```

Opera opens up. Is this what you were looking for?

If you want the default browser to open up a web page for you, you can type:

```
open http://foobar.com
```

[Reference for the more general solution.](http://osxdaily.com/2011/07/18/open-url-default-web-browser-command-line/)

CHEERS

Comment: Thanks! A bit, but I need somehow to hook it up with "x-www-browser" command. Maybe alias will help?

Comment: Nope, alias does not help, still got "x-www-browser: command not found"

Comment: @BartoszRychlicki I didn't quite understand. Ok, after a bit of "duckduckgo"ing I wasn't able to find a version of x-www-browser that works on the Mac. It seems this is a Linux thing. Or is it something tied in with "behat"? I'd never heard of "behat" before your posting. CHEERS

Comment: alias x-www-browser='open -a Chrome'

(Might also be Google Chrome for Chrome, but I don't have a Mac at hand right now.)

Comment: @BartoszRychlicki Put it in a script instead. Aliases are only expanded in interactive shells.

Comment: Try AppleScript, using the osascript command line tool. `man osascript`

Comment: I can't modify behat code and invoke something, behat is calling for  x-www-browser and I need to hookup to that :/

Answer (score 0):

Try AppleScript to control the browser, using the osascript command line tool. `man osascript`

More here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7276138